# jQuery to pass CSS var

Tags: jquery, css

I have the following setup to change the color of links within a certain class. For some reason it is not working. I do need to keep this structure for what I am doing. By default the color of the links are white as per the CSS which is working. Just the jQuery changing the links is not working.

```
var link_colour = "#CCC";

function linkcolor() {
$("[class='navLink']").css("color",link_colour);
}
window.onload = linkcolor;

<ul>
<li><a class="navLink" href="#"><img src="foo1.png" />xyz</a></li>
<li><a class="navLink" href="#"><img src="foo2.png" />abc</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you are using `jQuery` you never want to use `window.onload = fn`.  Use `$(document).ready(fn)` or just `$(fn)` for short.

```
$(linkcolor);
```

I'm guessing this code is running after the `window.onload` event fires, so your handler of the event never executes.  `jQuery` will handle this case by firing the function right away if the event already happened, ensuring the code gets executed.

[See it work here](http://jsfiddle.net/8n488/)

---

The other answers that say `$('.navLink')` is better are right as well.  But that's simply shorthand for the selector you have that should work fine.  You should change it, but that's not the problem.

Comment: wow. Thank you! I had been struggling with this for almost a week and now it works!

Answer (score 1):

Use:

```
$('.navLink')
```

This will work properly to select all elements with their class attribute set to `navLink`

Comment: And `$("[class='navLink']")` wouldn't?

Comment: Well it will work only if you make it like this: $('*[class="navLink"]') or $('a[class="navLink"]'), but for classes it's not a recommended way.

Answer (score 1):

Here is how you should express this in jQuery-friendly terms:

```
var link_colour = '#CCC';
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.navlink').css('color', link_colour);
});
```

Comment: What's the difference between this and mine? also $CCC is not a color.

Comment: @Arda  There really isn't a significant difference here other than I have the `link_colour` variable in global scope (just to match the scope of this variable in the original question as I wasn't sure if it had use elsewhere - likely having scope only within the function is sufficient).  I think we just answered around the same time, so I hadn't seen yours posted yet.

Answer (score 0):

I'd use the selector like this:

```
$(function(){
 var $color = '#CCC';
 $('.navLink').css('color',$color);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Three points there.

**1) Use $(document).ready**

You are using the window.reload, in this case, use the $(document).ready.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
// My code
});
```

**2) Use the .class**

Don't use the [class=''], use the .class instead.

```
$('.navLink')
```

These are my recommendations and my answer to your problem!

Comment: Ok, so removing from answer :)